# I have changed sdk version from 29 to 30

Tags: android-studio, storage, android-11

I have made a status saver app.I have used target sdk version 29 and it was working good.But when I changed it to 30 or higher it does not show status. I have improved all the libraries and dependedies that was suggested.
please help....
I have give some screenshoots... Please help,,,,If you feel easy we can disscus on whatsapp,massanger etc...as you wish.....
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0vaU.png
`[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMab1.png)
[pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAkGL.png)
[pic4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BbTF.png)

I have searched a lot but invain.....

Comment: please provide some code so we can understand what you implemented. how you get status.?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.